# Need a Grid to AngularJS application, is ng-Grid suitable for my needs

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have a AngularJS based Application which has complete table showing data.

Now it seems to be so that this table needs sorting too columns, cell editing, Dropdowns to cells and maybe paging.

I have checked ng-Grid but haven't found a feature that I need.

It's hierarchical presentation of parent and child rows. Only two dimensional presentation like e.g. below is needed

- Parent

  - Child 1
  - Child 2
  - Child 3

Has anyone of you used ng-Grid for these kinds of things? Can ng-Grid handle this?

I would be glad to get some advise how to handle especially this two dimensional hierarchical presentation.

Comment: If this hierarchy is only one level deep you can just use the aggregate grouping

Comment: Can anyone give an example of this kind of solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If this hierarchy is only one level deep you can just use the aggregate grouping. See also Grouping Example - HTML5 [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/#grouping)

To set the grouping immediately, you can just add the column to be grouped in your gridOptions

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
      data: 'myData', 
      columnDefs: [
        {field: 'name', displayName: 'Parent'},
        {field: 'price', displayName: 'Child'}
      ],
      groups: ['name'],
      /* headerRowHeight : 0 */
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [adapt-strap](http://adaptv.github.io/adapt-strap/). 
They have tree-browser grid as well as whole slew of other components needed in large-scale application. All the components are extremely light weight. http://adaptv.github.io/adapt-strap/